# Convert this object into array of key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

if we create one object like

```
const userDetails={firstname:'karan',lastname:'khimani'}
```

then expected output like

```
[["firstname", "karan"], ["lastname", "khimani"]]
```

How did i convert this?

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt on solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.entries`:

```js
const userDetails = { firstname: "karan", lastname: "khimani" };
const arr = Object.entries(userDetails);
console.log(arr);
```

I believe this is an ES7 feature - so if you need to support older browsers, use `map` with `Object.keys`:

```js
var userDetails = { firstname: "karan", lastname: "khimani" };
var arr = Object.keys(userDetails).map(function(key) {
  return [key, userDetails[key]]
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i'm getting `0:  ["firstname", "karan"]1: ["lastname", "khimani"]
` in different keys

Comment: @KaranKhimani Try pressing `Run code snippet` above, it works perfectly. I also believe what you're describing is a browser's console's way of showing the contents of an array.

Comment: exaclty  let me try

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is create an array, which contains keys and values as arrays.

You should have a look at `Object.keys` and `Object.entries`.

Soluce are below, but try to find it yourself first looking at the documentation of the functions I've given you.

---

```js
const userDetails = {
  firstname: 'karan',
  lastname: 'khimani'
};

const transformed = Object.keys(userDetails).map(x => [x, userDetails[x]]);

console.log(transformed);
```

---

Why not always use `Object.entries`? Because It's not well supported on every browser.

```js
const userDetails = {
  firstname: 'karan',
  lastname: 'khimani'
};

const transformed = Object.entries(userDetails);

console.log(transformed);
```

[image]

Comment: Getting console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'userDetails' has already been declared` @Grégory NEUT

Comment: I think that you copy pasted my code and appended it to your existing code. If you do so, the variable `userDetails` will be declared two times and that's why you have the error. Removes either your declaration or mine. You should follow a javascript tutorial